# Why did Jsoup move an HTML element when it was parsed?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Here is my sample input HTML Codes:

```
<html>
<head>
<object></object>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the output when parsed using Jsoup:

```
<html>
 <head> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <object></object>    
 </body>
</html>
```

Question: Why did Jsoup move the `<object>` tag from the `<head>` to the `<body>`?

Comment: Show us your parsing code.

Comment: Try to set Jsoup to parse the HTML as XML, which will ignore the arragement of tags in the document.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct behaviour since `<object>` **must** appear inside the body.

> ### HTML  Tag
>
> [...]
>
> #### Tips and Notes
>
> **Note:** An  element *must appear inside the  element*. The text between the  and  is an alternate text, for
>   browsers that do not support this tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

---

If you *want* the object within the head, you can use the `XmlParser` instead:

```
    final String html = "<html>\n"
            + "<head>\n"
            + "<object></object>\n"
            + "</head>\n"
            + "<body>\n"
            + "</body>\n"
            + "</html>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
    //                                   |<-------------->|
```